# How to pair android and ubuntu via KDE connect behind firewall [ufw]?

Tags: kde, android, ufw

I have my ufw setup in my ubuntu. I have problem with connecting KDE connect and my ubuntu pc behind firewall. How do I do it? Disabling firewall easily pairs the two device but I am having difficulty with firewall on.

Answer (score 10):

Just found a solution

https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect mentions that we need to enable rule in ufw.

so...

```
sudo ufw allow 1714:1764/udp
sudo ufw allow 1714:1764/tcp
```

And I needed to reboot my laptop for things to work.
Its working now like a charm with ufw running.

Comment: You don't need to reboot, just `sudo ufw reload` does the trick

Comment: In case it helps anyone else looking at this; I know the IP of my phone on my network, so I could add the following more explicit rules: 

```sudo ufw allow in on wlp2s0 proto tcp from 192.168.0.182 to any port 1714:1764

sudo ufw allow in on wlp2s0 proto udp from 192.168.0.182 to any port 1714:1764```

Comment: Is this just needed for discovery, or for all the features?

Answer (score 2):

To do this in a more complete and secure fashion, only opening ports to devices in your local network, open the console and enter:

`ip -4 addr`

Look for **inet** line that looks like:

inet **xxx.xxx.xxx**.xxx/24 brd xxx.xxx.xxx.255 **scope global**...

Now enter these commands for IPv4:

```
sudo ufw allow proto udp from xxx.xxx.xxx.0/24 to any port 1714:1764
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from xxx.xxx.xxx.0/24 to any port 1714:1764
```

Substitute **xxx.xxx.xxx** with your **inet** adress first 3 numbers as shown in bold.

Use the line with **scope global** at the end to find your correct adress, **don't use** the line with 127.0.0.1 adress:

For IPv6 just enter:

```
sudo ufw allow proto udp from fe80::/64 to any port 1714:1764
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from fe80::/64 to any port 1714:1764
```

fe80:://64 is the local link range for IPv6 connections (your IPv6 local network adresses).

Finally type:

```
sudo ufw reload
```

This way you don't have your ports open to the wild.

You can install **gufw** a graphical tool to manage your firewall rules and delete previously set ones for kdeconnect. To do that just enter:

```
sudo apt install gufw
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using ufw you can just use iptables itself.

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -i <your-interface> -p udp --dport 1714:1764 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT -i <your-interface> -p tcp --dport 1714:1764 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o <your-interface> -p tcp --sport 1714:1764 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o <your-interface> -p udp --sport 1714:1764 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```